Use regex function on Polars
I'm cleaning a column of spanish text using the following function that use re and unicodedata:
def CleanText(texto: str) -> str:
    texto = texto.lower()
    texto = ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', texto) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
    texto = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9 \n\.,]', '', texto)
    texto = re.sub(r'([.,])(?![\s])', r'\1 ', texto)
    texto = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', texto).strip()
    texto = texto.replace('.', '')
    texto = texto.replace(',', '')
    return texto

And then i apply it to my Dataframe using:
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("Comment").map_elements(CleanText,return_dtype=pl.String).alias("CleanedText")
        )
)

However, since polars accept regex crate i think i could just use polars to do the cleaning without needing to create auxiliar funcions.
How could i just use a polars expression to do the same?

Asking "What are your thoughts on this?" makes this question off topic as it is asking for an opinion. What is your real question? Are you asking how to do it all in one big complex expression within the polars? Putting it all in one big expression may seem clever, but it can make it difficult to maintain or add additional functionality. Please rewrite the last sentence.

Just edited my question, thanks

Two things:

currently regex crate doesn't support lookaheads, so I've adjusted the function a bit.
I don't think there's an native polars for normalizing unicode data yet, so you can either run or check this (undocumented?) pyarrow function - pyarrow.compute.utf8_normalize(). Check this question as well.

def CleanExpr(texto: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    texto = texto.str.to_lowercase()
    #texto = ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', texto) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
    texto = texto.str.replace_all(r'[^a-z0-9 \n\.,]', '')
    texto = texto.str.replace_all('.', ' ', literal=True)
    texto = texto.str.replace_all(',', ' ', literal=True)
    texto = texto.str.replace_all(r'\s+', ' ').str.strip_chars()
    texto = texto.str.replace_all('.', '', literal=True)
    texto = texto.str.replace_all(',', '', literal=True)
    return texto

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        CleanExpr(pl.col("Comment")).alias("CleanedText")
    )
)

